# Accessing layer's visibility presets?

Tags: pyqgis

Is there a way to programmatically access a layer's **visibility presets** defined in the *layer tree view* widget (methods, properties, etc.)?

To avoid misunderstandings the part I want to access is the one highlighted **in blue** in the following screen capture (ex. preset "Test-01" ...)

[image]

Comment: The question is not very clear, could you elaborate a bit more on what you intend to do? Perhaps through an example?

Comment: I think that the class you are looking for is this one https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsvisibilitypresets.h but i'm using qgis 2.4 and i think that presets are not in my system to make tests. I think that you can get it wiht iface.layerMenu()

Comment: That seems to be THE answer Francisco but i don't find any trace of this class in the API documentation and i don't see how i should call it so far ... I'm using QGIS 2.6

Comment: Can anybody tell me if the class **QgsVisibilityPresets** really exists ? i don't clearly understand the online documentation ...

Comment: @snaileater The link provided by Francisco refers to a class in the app folder of the QGIS source code, which is not exposed to Python bindings. Classes in the core or gui folder are offered in PyQGIS, but not QgsVisibilityPresets.

Comment: @gcarillo Thanks for explanation ... It was quite confusing to a newbie like me ... That means that C++ programmers have access to more functionalities then ... ? What is this limitation due to ? So ... if i'm experimenting in PyQGIS i only look in **core** and **gui** ... Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the visibilityPresetCollection through the project instance:

```
QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection()
```

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVisibilityPresetCollection.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using QGIS 3.0 freshly released, instead of

```
QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection()
```

you now have to use the following:

```
QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
```

as stated in [QGIS 3.0 API Backwards Incompatible Changes](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_QgsProject)

Then, you can get themes names with:

```
QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection().mapThemes()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def activate_visibility_preset(preset_name, *, project=None, coll=None):
  """Activates a visibility preset by its name.
  Return a boolean indicating success."""
  # https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f044c95fd8927d86967ce8af3930bdc7523095fa/src/app/qgsmapthemes.cpp#L138
  if project is None:
    project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
  if coll is None:
    coll = project.mapThemeCollection()
  if not coll.hasMapTheme(preset_name):
    return False
  root = project.layerTreeRoot()
  model = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().model()
  coll.applyTheme(preset_name, root, model)
  return True

def active_visibility_preset(*, project=None, coll=None):
  """Return the name of the active visibility preset or
  None if no active visibility preset."""
  # https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f044c95fd8927d86967ce8af3930bdc7523095fa/src/app/qgsmapthemes.cpp#L210
  if project is None:
    project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
  if coll is None:
    coll = project.mapThemeCollection()
  root = project.layerTreeRoot()
  model = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().model()
  curr_mapthemecollection = coll.createThemeFromCurrentState(root, model)
  for preset_name in visibility_presets(project=project, coll=coll):
    checking_preset = coll.mapThemeState(preset_name)
    if checking_preset == curr_mapthemecollection:
      return preset_name

def visibility_presets(*, project=None, coll=None):
  """Return the names of the visibility presets in a list."""
  # https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f044c95fd8927d86967ce8af3930bdc7523095fa/src/app/qgsmapthemes.cpp#L149
  if project is None:
    project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
  if coll is None:
    coll = project.mapThemeCollection()
  preset_names = coll.mapThemes()
  return preset_names
```

Usage:

```
>>> visibility_presets()
['Test-01']
>>> activate_visibility_preset('Test-01')
True
>>> active_visibility_preset()
'Test-01'
```

Tested on QGIS 3.10.14

Note that you might want to refresh the canvas after changing visibility preset:

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

[Code on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/SzieberthAdam/7a728e1df612fd0d30b525782f6e6c52) (if you upvote here I would appreciate a star there too)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your layer for example as:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
```

You should get legend:

```
legend = iface.legendInterface()
```

Then you can check layers visibility (it returns bool):

```
legend.isLayerVisible(layer)
```

Or toggle visibility:

```
# off
legend.setLayerVisible(layer, False)
# on
legend.setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```

Comment: yeah thanks i knew these one but u describe a *per layer* access, my question is about the whole visibility preset (which is a set of "checked" layers) ... how can we access the members of the set, the name of the set, how can we activate a set and/or switch to another ? ...

Comment: To be more precise (maybe...) is there a Qgis Class related to these layers visibility presets (i hope i use the right english name, sorry...) ?

Comment: If you want to get set of visible layers you have to use for loop on all layers and add them to list or something like that. There isn't any class related to all visible or invisible layers. Maybe layers group, but it isn't related with visibility.