# QGIS switch Visibility Presets using Python

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to switch visibility preset using python but I cannot find any relevant method in the [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsVisibilityPresetCollection.html) . Does anyone knows how I can do it?
The VisibilityPresetCollection class is accessible using the following code `QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection()`.[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Accessing layer's visibility presets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153648/accessing-layers-visibility-presets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def to_print():
    layers= iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for layer in layers:
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, False)

    layer_list = QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection().presetVisibleLayers(u'to_print')
    for layer in layer_list:
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(layer), True)



def to_work():
    layers= iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for layer in layers:
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, False)

    layer_list = QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection().presetVisibleLayers(u'to_work')
    for layer in layer_list:
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(layer), True)
```

Here you go! i think this will work for you.

At first you hide every layer, then extract the layers of the selected preset and set them to visible one-by-one though the loop

Answer (score 0):

Please view my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255304/44921

Usage:

```
>>> visibility_presets()
['Test-01']
>>> activate_visibility_preset('Test-01')
True
>>> active_visibility_preset()
'Test-01'
```

Tested on QGIS 3.10.14